# How to fix an internal server error in my Flask program

Tags: python, flask

When I run the program and click the button to use this function, I get an internal server error that I don't know how to fix. I only get the server error and uncompleted request whether the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application

This is the route for the register function

```
 @myapp_obj.route('/register', methods =['GET', 'POST'])
    def register():
        msg = ''
        if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form and 'email' in request.form :
            username = request.form['username']
            password = request.form['password']
            email = request.form['email']
            db.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = % s', (username, ))
            if db.fetchone()[0]:
                msg = 'Account already exists !'
            else:
                u = User(username, password, email)
                db.session.add(u)
                db.session.commit()
                msg = 'You have successfully registered !'
        elif request.method == 'POST':
            msg = 'Please fill out the form !'
        return render_template('register.html', msg = msg)
```

HTML code for the route
register.html

```
 <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title> Register </title>           
        </head>
        <body>
            <div align="left">
            <div align="left" class="border">
                <div class="header">
                    <h1 class="word">Register</h1>
                </div></br>
                <h2 class="word">
                    <form action="{{ url_for('register') }}" method="POST">
                    <div class="msg">{{ msg }}</div>
                        <input id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Username" class="textbox"/></br>
              <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Email ID" class="textbox"/></br>
                        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Enter Your Password" class="textbox"/></br>
                        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="textbox"/></br>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Sign Up"></br>
                    </form>
                </h2>
                <p class="bottom">Already have an account? <a class="bottom" href="{{url_for('login')}}"> Sign In here</a></p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You should provide a complete error message to allow anybody to help you. There are not enough information in your post to do it

Comment: There are probably log messages from flask that indicate the cause of the error. What do they say? Providing a single (misformatted) function doesn't really help us out; ideally, you can provide us with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can run to see the problem you're describing.